# How to provide SQL initial data for third party application in Django

Tags: python, sql, django

I'm using a third party application in my Django project (photologue) and I wonder if it is possible to provide initial sql data for this application the same way I do with my own.

As the application is installed in the central python site package, and I don't want/can  create an sql file there (and doubt that it will work that way). I tried adding one in my Django project and creating  an sql folder with the required sql files but without success.

So my question is this:

- Is it possible to provide initial sql data for third party applications
- Is there any way (hook) to do so without passing by a customization of the manager.py script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can provide initial SQL data or fixtures:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/#providing-initial-sql-data
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/#providing-initial-data-with-fixtures

The `sql` solution will work only for syncdb upon creation of models of the app containing the folder.

For other apps You might wanna take the fixtures route, as you can specify there what ever models you want. The you can either load them with `manage.py loaddata` command, or, if you'll name the file `initial_data.[xml/yaml/json]` (extension depending  on format), it will be loaded on syncdb, just note the warning that comes with it:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/#automatically-loading-initial-data-fixtures

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm already using this but it seams that you can do the same with third party applications. May be I'm missing something, can you explain how to do it ?

Comment: I've updated the answer, expanded on fixtures. If you can provide an example of the sql file your trying to use it'll be grear

Comment: Thanks, I hoped to use sql file, but will go with the fixture solution as it seems more appropriate.